# Looking for values based on some conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a sheet that has the attendance reports submitted by instructors through a Google forms for different courses in different weeks.

I need to generate an attendance sheet for each course automatically as shown in the images below.

Your support is highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: Thanks @Giacomo1968. I attempted several times with LOOKUP functions (VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, and XLOOKUP) but I always get N/A as a result. I could not get the correct formula. I know I have to match 3 values (course, week, and student).

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show your attempts? If you have been able to at least try something, this community is ready to help you. But if you are simply leaving this question as-is, it would be considered a scripting request which is not what this site is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe HLOOKUP MATCH and Concatenate Operator '&' should give you the required results.
See the below screenshot. In this example I am purposely using numbers in attendance sheet just to test it out and confirm that it's working.
Please verify at your end and check if this works for you or not.

[image]

For the output table the Course Name is in J1 and the table as seen in the screenshot.

Now in K3 put the following formula.

```
=HLOOKUP($J3,$C$2:$G$9,MATCH(K$2&$J$1,$C$2:$C$9&$D$2:$D$9,0),FALSE)
```

Note the relative and absolute references required for this to work correctly.

It simply uses HLOOKUP on the input table but uses Concatenate Operator in MATCH function to join the two columns and search together on Week & Student Name.

Drag the formula across the entire table.

You may use IFERROR to return a meaningful text if the data is not found as in this case there's no data for Wk4 for the given combination.

Depending upon your regional settings you might need to replace comma with semicolon in the formula as list separator just in case.

---

**Edit1**

See below screenshot for Google Sheets

[image]

```
=ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP($J3,$C$2:$G$9,MATCH(K$2&$J$1,arrayformula($C$2:$C$9&$D$2:$D$9),0),FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks @patkim for your help. I appreciate your efforts and time. Your solution works on MS Excel, but it does not work on Google Sheets. I cannot include the concatenate operator "&" in the MATCH function. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: @attavip If you do not want an answer for Excel, why did you tag your question only with `microsoft-excel`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, my bad. I thought the answer would work.

Comment: @attavip See Edit1 above

Comment: @patkim Thank you very much. This has resolved the issue. I appreciate your help.